# Problem with defining the proper trigger type in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

what I want is simple. I wanted one of my table to update its row each time a SELECT was made on it. So I've done this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dateSelectionTrain BEFORE SELECT ON Train FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE Train
    SET derniereSelection = SYSDATE
    WHERE numero = :NEW.numero;
END;
```

I only want to update the row that was selected in the SELECT.

When I tried to create the trigger I had this message:

```
ORA-04072: invalid trigger type
```

So I wanted to know, is their any way at all to update a table each time a select is made ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never heard of any database that would make a trigger work when you select. A SELECT  is not an action that changes the data. Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: In my database, I'm managing train wich makes trips. When I select train from my table Train I want the distance column to be updated if this particular train made any trip since the last select.

Comment: If you need this derived value to be stored, why not store it when the trip is recorded?  That would be the normal way to do things.

Comment: I hadn't though of that. Well thanks I think I'll just do that then!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Oracle supports a SELECT type trigger.

Comment: In this case, is their some way (other than trigger perhaps) to acomplish this ?

Comment: Not really.  You can audit the selects, and then try to mine the audit trail - but you can't UPDATE a table by issuing a SELECT.